# How to append results from a for loop in a DataFrame

Tags: python, back-testing

I have created a function that manipulates a couple of datasets and outputs a merged DataFrame. I have passed an array of variables in a loop, which outputs a merged DataFrame for each one - now, I want all the results appended in a single DataFrame:

Function:

```
def backtest(ticker, data):
    fin = si.get_data(ticker)
    fin.index.rename('date', inplace=True)
    fin = fin.reset_index(level=0)
    fin = fin.drop(columns=['high', 'low', 'volume'])
    fin['intraday_ch_usd'] = fin['close'] - fin['open']
    fin['intraday_pct_ch'] = fin['intraday_ch_usd'] / fin['open'] * 100
    fin['3d_pr'] = fin['close'].shift(-3)
    fin['3d_del'] = fin['3d_pr'] - fin['open']
    fin['3d_pct_ch'] = fin['3d_del'] / fin['open'] * 100
    data = data[data['awardee_parent_ticker_symbol'].notna()]
    data = data.rename(columns={'date_of_news_dispatch': 'date', 'awardee_parent_ticker_symbol': 'ticker'})
    data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])
    data = data.merge(fin, on=['date','ticker'])
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Loop:

```
output=pd.DataFrame()
for ticker in tickers:     
    try:
       backtest(ticker, data)
    except:
        pass
    output=output.append(data,ignore_index=True)
output
```

I can't figure out how to append results in a single DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you should not dynamically append rows to a DataFrame. To achieve the result you want, you can append everything in a list and then call `pd.concat` to create a DataFrame from it. Something like

```
output=[]
for ticker in tickers:     
    try:
       backtest(ticker, data)
    except:
        pass
    output.append(data)
output = pd.concat(output)
```